# Django: is there a difference in performance between .filter(key__in=set) and .filter(key__in=list)

Tags: python, django

I'm asking this question in the context where I already have a list and I'm wondering if it's worth converting it into a set to use in the filter query or not, i.e. which is better:

```py
some_set = set(some_list)
some_qs = SomeModel.objects.filter(some_key__in=some_set)
```

vs

```py
some_qs = SomeModel.objects.filter(some_key__in=some_list)
```

I know that if you want to lookup the elements from a list `a` in another list `b`, it's generally worth converting list `b` into a set since `x in list` is O(n) and `x in set` is O(1). But I don't know how Django implements the query filter `__in` so I'm not sure which is the better option in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be DB system specific so first of all I should mention that I'm using PostgreSQL.

Following blue_note's suggestion, I had a look at the query execution plan with `.explain()` and it was identical (except for the order of items) for a list that has each item repeated 4 times, and for a set with the same items. This means that Django does some sort of list to set conversion internally. Next, I used `timeit` to see which of the two approaches is faster and it turned out that converting the list to a set first is faster. Here's my code:

```py
from timeit import timeit

qs = SomeModel.objects.all()

l = [str(x.id) for x in qs]

l.extend(l)
l.extend(l)

def t_l():
  return SomeModel.objects.filter(id__in=l)

def t_s():
  return SomeModel.objects.filter(id__in=set(l))

>>> SomeModel.objects.filter(id__in=l).explain()
"Bitmap Heap Scan on authentication_permissionsvatnumber  (cost=9.26..19.48 rows=8 width=86)\n  Recheck Cond: (id = ANY ('{824ea540-6fac-4929-b5cc-306890356ca1,349d3d2d-f8f8-45b7-9e80-538189b455e4,7d1bc4aa-9442-4fbc-a419-67f56483cd8c,8dd98c0e-e792-4b5c-80f6-c08de202b888,0dfddb54-19ae-4204-82a3-183ec01efb83,93c1fb80-b464-4651-b8c3-7928eaf56790,7d7aa210-1979-4f90-8680-a3dc7e685a71,6db11e75-6fae-421e-bda5-be22b1b2e82a}'::uuid[]))\n  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on authentication_permissionsvatnumber_pkey  (cost=0.00..9.26 rows=8 width=0)\n        Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{824ea540-6fac-4929-b5cc-306890356ca1,349d3d2d-f8f8-45b7-9e80-538189b455e4,7d1bc4aa-9442-4fbc-a419-67f56483cd8c,8dd98c0e-e792-4b5c-80f6-c08de202b888,0dfddb54-19ae-4204-82a3-183ec01efb83,93c1fb80-b464-4651-b8c3-7928eaf56790,7d7aa210-1979-4f90-8680-a3dc7e685a71,6db11e75-6fae-421e-bda5-be22b1b2e82a}'::uuid[]))"

>>> SomeModel.objects.filter(id__in=set(l)).explain()
"Bitmap Heap Scan on authentication_permissionsvatnumber  (cost=9.26..19.48 rows=8 width=86)\n  Recheck Cond: (id = ANY ('{0dfddb54-19ae-4204-82a3-183ec01efb83,8dd98c0e-e792-4b5c-80f6-c08de202b888,93c1fb80-b464-4651-b8c3-7928eaf56790,7d7aa210-1979-4f90-8680-a3dc7e685a71,6db11e75-6fae-421e-bda5-be22b1b2e82a,349d3d2d-f8f8-45b7-9e80-538189b455e4,7d1bc4aa-9442-4fbc-a419-67f56483cd8c,824ea540-6fac-4929-b5cc-306890356ca1}'::uuid[]))\n  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on authentication_permissionsvatnumber_pkey  (cost=0.00..9.26 rows=8 width=0)\n        Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{0dfddb54-19ae-4204-82a3-183ec01efb83,8dd98c0e-e792-4b5c-80f6-c08de202b888,93c1fb80-b464-4651-b8c3-7928eaf56790,7d7aa210-1979-4f90-8680-a3dc7e685a71,6db11e75-6fae-421e-bda5-be22b1b2e82a,349d3d2d-f8f8-45b7-9e80-538189b455e4,7d1bc4aa-9442-4fbc-a419-67f56483cd8c,824ea540-6fac-4929-b5cc-306890356ca1}'::uuid[]))"


>>> timeit(t_l, number=10000)
0.9831858319999967

>>> timeit(t_s, number=10000)
0.7851520270000023
```

But I also wanted to see what happens when the list and the set already have the same number of unique elements:

```py
>>> timeit(t_l, number=10000)
0.8463515899999976

>>> timeit(t_s, number=10000)
0.7903294700000174
```

As it turns out converting the list to a set first is still faster, although by a much smaller margin. If I were to take a guess, it looks to me like Django always runs some sort of list to set conversion internally, before submitting the query to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, you can print `my_query.explain()` to see if there's any difference between the two options. In you case it's very unlikely, since `x in set` does happen on the SQL side, not on the python side, and django will convert your iterable to string before sending it to sql.